# Google API Error: Null Pointer Exception (Is Google API recently made un available by google?)

Tags: java, eclipse, google-api

I have a web project developed in Jsf 1.2, Richfaces 3.3, Jdk 1.7, Tomcat Server 7.0.55 and gson 2.2.1.jar using eclipse IDE 3.4. I am using google api example from  [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/05/call-google-search-api-in-java-program/)  in eclipse to retrieve results. My application was functioning correctly retrieving results. However, all of a sudden i have started receiving error. My code snippet is as follows:-

```
public class SearchBean  {
.
.
.

public void search() throws IOException {   


    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i = i + 4) 
              {
        String address = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&start="+i+"&q=";
        String query = "Semantics";
        String charset = "UTF-8";


        URL url = new URL(address + URLEncoder.encode(query, charset));
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), charset);
        GoogleResults results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, GoogleResults.class);
        GoogleList gList = new GoogleList();




        for (int m = 0; m <= 3; m++) 
          {
            try {
                      System.out.println(results.getResponseData().getResults().get(m).getTitle()));     // line no 2076 generating error
                  System.out.println(results.getResponseData().getResults().get(m).getUrl()));

                }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

          }


         }



}   


class GoogleResults{

private ResponseData responseData;
public ResponseData getResponseData() { return responseData; }
public void setResponseData(ResponseData responseData) { this.responseData = responseData; }
public String toString() { return "ResponseData[" + responseData + "]"; }

static class ResponseData {
    private List<Result> results;
    public List<Result> getResults() { return results; }
    public void setResults(List<Result> results) { this.results = results; }
    public String toString() { return "Results[" + results + "]"; }
}

static class Result {
    private String url;
    private String title;
    public String getUrl() { return url; }
    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public void setUrl(String url) { this.url = url; }
    public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
    public String toString() { return "Result[url:" + url +",title:" + title + "]"; }
}

}
```

And the error i received is :-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.bean.SearchBean.search(SearchBean.java:2076)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
at org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodExpression.invoke(JspMethodExpression.java:70)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.broadcast(UIDataAdaptor.java:1364)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:324)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:299)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:256)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processDecodes(AjaxViewRoot.java:412)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What could be possible cause of generation of this error all of a sudden.
I am new to Java and all. so please forego any naive-ness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you get a NullPointerException from a line like this:

```
System.out.println(results.getResponseData().getResults().get(m).getTitle()));
```

you can see that either `results`, `.getResponseData()`, `.getResults()` or `.get(m)` is null.

Then you have to check which one of those is being null, and ensure that it is being initialized.

Comment: i checked one by one. results.getResponseData().getResults() is null

Comment: Then the results instance has not been initialized. I'm not very familiar with the Gson library, but are you sure it can load an instance of `List` directly? What about using an array instead?

Comment: my question is that has google api abandoned by google? because till last week this code was working.